# Javascript (unsolved) - Passing variables inside a function to an onclick function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a variable from an addEventListener function to an onclick function. Thank you!

```
       document.getElementById('rect').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
     var index = 5;

     }
    asd.onclick = function() {



    }
```

Comment: You call `hey(index)`?

Comment: inside fuction hey ()? I need the variable index inside the function hey

Comment: as part of the `onclick` handler

Comment: I changed it now, I had another function without name, cause it's an addeventlistener @DanielA.White

Comment: So, I don't have the name to use hey(index)

Comment: You should explain in more detail what it is you want to do. And you should probably stick with one way to use event listeners - either `el.onclick = function`, or `el.addEventListener('click', function, false)`

Comment: you might want to look at reactiveextensions

Comment: @DanielA.White  Unfortunately I can't use jquerry or any other library

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way

```
asd.onclick = function() {
  var index = 5;
  hey(index);
}

 function hey (index) {
  var recive = index;
  console.log(index);
 }
```

Comment: @Andy I changed the second function to add.eventlistener which doesn't have a name. How could I pass a variable if both of the functions don't have a name?

Comment: Or what if it's the other way around, what if I have a variable in the function hey and I want to pass it to the onclick function?